# Allow USB debugging for any PC without confirmation

Tags: adb, usb-debugging

My phone display slowly turned black for an unknown reason; Maybe moisture (SM-A320F Android8 - no root). I use scrcpy to show phone screen on my PC (and voice assistant when I don't have access to any PC). This software needs USB debugging.

I checked "Always allow USB debugging..." for my PC. However, each time I use Nox android emulator, computer RSA key changes and I should confirm it again. Once voice assistant stopped working in this situation and I luckily and hardly found Allow button in dialog by guess.

Is there any way to always allow USB debugging from any PC? I know it will cause security risks but if both scrcpy and voice assistant stop working again, maybe I can't find Allow button! I tried `adb disable-verity` but ADB says:

```
D:\scrcpy>adb disable-verity
disable-verity only works for userdebug builds
verity cannot be disabled/enabled - USER build
```

Comment: To avoid adb authentication problems I recommend to you to install and use only adb from Android SDK. scrcpy contains an own adb version which I would not use. Set the system environment variable `ADB` and let it point to the adb binary of the Android SDK then scrcpy uses Android SDK adb. Also make sure to use the same Windows user profile so you always use the same adb authentication key.

Comment: @Robert I added ADB to path and deleted ADB from scrcpy directory. But still have to confirm USB debugging after running Nox emulator.

Comment: Check what happens to the files `adbkey` and `adbkey.pub` in the directory ``%userprofile%\.android\``. I assume NOX replaces them which is a very bad behavior. Backup those files before starting NOX and restore them afterwards. These files are your identity the device authenticates ADB for. If they are changed or deleted the authorization is gone.

Comment: Additionally you should send this issue to the developers of Nox. Deleting/replacing the adbkey is a big bug.

Comment: @Robert Thanks about that path. I edited permissions of `adbkey` and `adbkey.pub` so they aren't editable now. However, I still want to disable confirmation. Is there any way to do this (actually without root)?

Comment: keep a copy of that keys safe in a zip somewhere in your emails or cloud, you can use that from any PC

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a cross post to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1575661/computer-rsa-key-changes-each-time-i-use-nox-android-player)

Comment: @Robert They aren't same. This one is about disabling USB debugging dialog in android phone. That one is about preventing RSA key change in windows. This question isn't answered yet.

Comment: OK then let me answer it: what you want is not possible without root respectively a custom ROM with adapted adbd on the device.

Comment: @Robert Thanks. You may post it as an answer so I can mark it as accepted answer.